# GameObjects go in different directions Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the most important part of the script:

```
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This is suppose to make my gameobject go in the right direction but if I am rotating the gameobject 180*, right becomes left, how can I make it so right remains right.

I Created an empty gameobject called "Obstacle" object where I store 2 of those objects called "hand"
So I have 2child objects called hand in the parent Obstacle, I want right to be right for all of them no matter if they are rotated or anything.

I also want to animate them, I did a test and animating the objects won't move them anymore' at all.

It initialise the object but it is not moving.

Comment: @DerPhysiker, thank you! that was useful, the only problem now is the animation, any idea how can I solve that.
I animate to rotate, and then I use the script from above in the parent to move them, but they are not moving.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a version of Unity installed on my current PC and cannot check now, but are you sure the parent is applying the script to the children? If you use this script inside the parent, this will move the parent itself and not the children.

Comment: It was an error from Unity, I managed to fix it .
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the first part of your question:

`transform.translate` acts in the relative space of the object and is aligned with its own axes, not with the world. So, if you rotate the object, `Vector.right` will return the right direction in that precise reference frame. If you want the object to always move right, independent on their orientation, you might want to try something like `transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);` instead as described here in the official documentation: [docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html).

Answer (score 2):

use following code

```
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

explanation:
Vector2.right gives (1,0) each time no matter what.

transform.right gives vector which has direction as right relative to transform and magnitude as 1.